# Compare two images to find differences

Tags: excel, vba, image, compare

I have this code on my userform to compare two loaded pictures.
Unfortunately I am getting an compile error with info that:

> "Method or data member not found".

I have no idea why I got it.

For any help, suggestion, thanks in advance.

```
Private Sub cmdGo_Click()

Dim wid As Integer
Dim hgt As Integer
Dim are_identical As Boolean
Dim X As Integer
Dim Y As Integer

    Screen.MousePointer = vbHourglass
    DoEvents

    ' Load the images.
    pic1.Picture = LoadPicture("d:\face2.bmp")
    pic2.Picture = LoadPicture("d:\face2.bmp")

    ' Size the difference image.
    wid = Min(pic1.ScaleWidth, pic2.ScaleWidth)
    hgt = Min(pic1.ScaleHeight, pic2.ScaleHeight)
    picResult.Width = wid + (picResult.Width - picResult.ScaleWidth)
    picResult.Height = wid + (picResult.Height - picResult.ScaleHeight)

    ' Create the difference image.
    are_identical = True
    For X = 0 To wid - 1
        For Y = 0 To hgt - 1
            If pic1.POINT(X, Y) = pic2.POINT(X, Y) Then
                picResult.PSet (X, Y), vbWhite
            Else
                picResult.PSet (X, Y), vbRed
                are_identical = False
            End If
        Next Y
    Next X

    If (pic1.ScaleWidth <> pic2.ScaleWidth) Or (pic1.ScaleHeight <> pic2.ScaleHeight) Then are_identical = False
    If are_identical Then
        MsgBox "The images are identical"
    Else
        MsgBox "The images are different"
    End If
    Screen.MousePointer = vbDefault
End Sub
```

Comment: What line throws the error?

Comment: This one: picResult.Width = wid + (picResult.Width - picResult.ScaleWidth)

it stop and mark this: "ScaleWidth"

Comment: Definition`ofpicResult`? same type (bmp, jpg, ....)? Use a [hash-function](https://en.wikibooks.org/wiki/Visual_Basic_for_Applications/String_Hashing_in_VBA) (if diff types, convert to same (e.g bmp) set orientation to same) to check for diffs, without looping through millions of pixels,

Comment: The format is the same (.bmp), size (width x height and resolution) the same, orientation the same, size of both are very small (200x200 pixels.). This small program I need to my class, so the task isn't so extremely complicated, but anyway it makes me a lot of trouble.

Comment: I need to looping through all pixels to create new pictures (BMP) which will have to colors of pixels, red if on compared pictures both pixels are different and white if are the same :-).